# react native firebase auth signInAnonymously determine the client (e.g. mobile, web)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

I want to know in my firebase function from which client (e.g. Mobile, Web) a new user signed up. I am using the signInAnonymously method of firebase client to sign up for a new user.

Since we don't have control over this API on cloud function. We are just listening to the onCreate event of the Users table. It has the following data.

```
{ email: null,
  emailVerified: false,
  displayName: null,
  photoURL: null,
  phoneNumber: null,
  disabled: false,
  providerData: [],
  customClaims: {},
  passwordSalt: null,
  passwordHash: null,
  tokensValidAfterTime: null,
  metadata: 
   UserRecordMetadata {
     creationTime: '2020-08-05T11:57:21Z',
     lastSignInTime: '2020-08-05T11:57:21Z' },
  uid: '',
  toJSON: [Function] }
```

Is there any way to determine?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "from which client a new user signed up".  Please edit the question to clarify, perhaps illustrating with an example and the code that you're working with.

Comment: @DougStevenson, It's included in the title. I have also edited the body.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Auth accounts are universal among all client platforms.  There is no identifier that you can use, within the account itself, to know how the user signed up.  If a user creates an account on Android, it's fully expected that they should be able to sign in on web and iOS with the same account and same credentials.

If you want to store some data on your own at the time of signup, outside Firebase Auth, you are free to do that.